# Can't configure nginx for multiple domains

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to host multiple domains (with simple static pages) on a single VPS, running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, nginx. The basic nginx configs for all domains are similar to this one (all separated in sites-available dir) :

```
server { 
 listen 80; 
 server_name www.example.com; 
 return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri; 
}

server { 
 listen 80; 
 server_name example.com;

 root /home/username/example.com; 
 index index.html; 
}
```

it works for first domain, for second domain it works only if I removed the first server block, for third domain it doesn't work at all. nginx fails to start. I don't what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You'll need to actually post the configuration which is giving you trouble.

Comment: I just found the solution, in the nginx error log it was saying "could not build the server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64". I think it was due to the longer domain names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems was the lengthy domain names. When I checked the nginx error log, I found this error message:

```
could not build the server_names_hash, 
you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64
```

So, I un-commented the following line in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file.

```
http {
 ....
 #server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
 ....
}
```

Now, everything works as expected :)

Comment: Holy crap, I had the same problem. Thanks! The limit in default nginx seems to be 14 characters per domain, which seems ridiculously short.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your sub-domains on localhost you may have to add the name of it to your local hosts file.
normally localted in /etc/hosts

Somehow those sub domains have to be resolved, try adding sub.localhost 127.0.0.1, and if your going to the web add an A record with your server ip, and check the DNS with

dig www.myexample.com

it should come back with an IP if its working, and do the same with each sub domain.

Let me know if this works

Comment: I don't think it's a DNS issue here, nginx fails to start - so that's where the problem lies. BTW, I've tested that by editing my `/etc/hosts` file - it works fine when the server is running.

Comment: Does Nginx give you any sort of error when restarting or does it just start a new command line without any feedback?

Comment: no, i don't get any error. It doesn't start or restart(if already running) silently.

Comment: thats usually because you have a syntax error in your config, please check this for multiple domains;

http://pastebin.com/nFxHhFjb
This usses sub domains but the template is easily adapted for more domains

Comment: syntax error ? where exactly, can you please clarify that.

Comment: It would be easier to debug if you edit your question with the actual domainnames.

Comment: @etagenklo my main problem is that "with above configuration" I can't even start the nginx server.

Answer (score 0):

Change the "return 301" to "rewrite..."

```
server { 
 listen 80; 
 server_name www.example.com; 
 rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://example.com$request_uri; 
}
```